# In a world where you had to pay for words, which words would be the most expensives?

Tags: economy, language

Imagine a world where you would have to pay for each word you spoke or wrote. I wondered which words (or which kind of) would be the most expensive ones? I assume it would not only be a matter of frequency, but also the quality of expression would be relevant. Likewise, there would also be words which are "cheap". So by which criteria would you determine the value of words in such a world?

EDIT: Иво Недев made a good point, so let us assume that it is not possible to invent new words, unless they are published by the government (like in a 1984 scenario).

EDIT: Concerning prices, let us assume a free market. The government only determines the words. (Javert proposed another scenario, a dictatorship, which would have a completely different impact on this question. Answers could discuss this as well.)

Comment: Who is the guy/company selling those words? ultimately HE is the one fixing the prices and is likely to want to maximize his profit

Comment: I'd say "innit" should be the most expensive along with "yerknow"

Comment: Who is imposing the price and for what goal?

Comment: Poor people will develop their own language with cheep words that will have the exact same meaning of expensive words.
For isntance if LOVE costs 1000$ to say once, but smakadudle costs 1$ I'll rather use the later, or figure out a way around the limitation - sign language etc.

Comment: Who do you have to pay? And what happens if you don't?

Comment: As it stands the question is *too broad* in my opinion. Can you impose additional constraints? I find the comment of Иво Недев highly valid in this context.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I will give it some thoughts and try to add some constraints.

Comment: First, it depends considerably on the language and the culture. It depends on how the initial prices are set and what can make it evolves. But *in fine* it is a matter of the opinion of the one(s) setting the price.

Comment: Do you pay for spoken/written words afterwards, or have to buy them in advance?

Comment: Adding some more on the setting might help narrow down the options here. If we're looking at a free-market economy then the answer is vastly different from a tightly regulated market.

Comment: Who "produces" and sells the words in this free market? Do listeners charge speakers or does the government charge them? Without a lot more details about the workings of your pay-per-word setup, anything goes.

Comment: How Carrollian of you.  'When I make a word do a lot of work like that,' said Humpty Dumpty, 'I always pay it extra.'

Comment: Loltax!  Youtube finally manages to make a revenue stream out of stupid viewer comments.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the views of society, any curse words or sexual words could definitely be expensive.

Maybe a system with price categories something like this:

- Daily use words: Often used and cheap. Say good morning and goodbye to your family.
- Work related words: Possibly free, since they're essential.
- Curse words: You're rich and you want to insult/curse? Pay up, son.
- Naughty words: For those looking for excitement. They will cost you but not as much as cursing.
- Lovely words: Cheaper than naughty words but more expensive than daily use words since saying "I love you" is still quite important.

Just a rough example, as it would be very hard to set a price on any individual word.

Comment: I like this approach as it covers also a moral function of language in society.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most expensive words are the words that express the **need** for something like : help me, give me something, lend me money ... By the way in my opinion **money** related words should be far more expensive.

---

**2nd Answer** :

If you live under a **dictatorship**, the government will put very high prices on words such as : freedom, revolution, rebellion, assassination, human rights, dignity ... etc. At the same time, this government will put cheap prices on words such as : security, obedience, dominance, unity, peace ... etc.

Comment: This is very interesting! If "need" words were cheap, it would mean that the society is very stable and supportive; instead, if such words were expensive, it could mean that the society is very poor regarding mutual assistance.

Comment: "Emergency" words and phrases, such as "help me" should be free of charge, similarly to emergency phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important criteria would be price/frequency. Words that are grammatically necessary will be spoken or written way more and will therefore be very cheap while other more special words that see almost no use would be exorbitantly high priced so the ratio of price/frequency will be the same for both. In the end you only got to define your desired ratio and apply it on all the words, that way you can easily adjust prices as well. (And also finally people who do studies on the frequency of words will make some money)